# Extract and validate data from attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

I'm using [`paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to manage my file uploads in rails.

From the attachments users give me, I'd like to extract some data to associate with the model the attachment is associated with.

```
has_attached_file :resume, #...
# ...
def extract_resume_summary
  path_to_resume = self.resume.queued_for_write[:original].path
  extracted = parse_resume_file(path_to_resume)
  self.number_of_jobs = extracted.number_of_jobs
  self.highest_level_of_education = extracted.highest_level_of_education
rescue ResumeParseError => e
  @problem_with_resume = e.message
end
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly *when* and *where* to do this.

I could use a custom [`Paperclip::Processor`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Processor):

```
class ::Paperclip::Summary < ::Paperclip::Processor
  def make
    @attachment.instance.extract_resume_summary
    Tempfile.new('unused')
  end
end
# ...
has_attached_file :resume, 
                  :styles => { :summary => {} }, 
                  :processors => [ :summary ] }, #...
```

But the fit isn't great. I think processors are intended to create new files (which I don't need, and thus the spurious `Tempfile`).

Also my extraction might fail, which means my user gave me bad data. I want that to be a validation-time problem, so I can report it along with other validation errors, and post-processing happens strictly AFTER validation.

I've tried hacking it in at initialization:

```
validate :successfully_parses_resume

def successfully_parses_resume
  errors.add(:resume, @problem_with_resume) if @problem_with_resume
end

def initialize(attributes=nil, options={})
  super
  extract_resume_summary
end
```

But I'm not quite sure that's right either, as that's not only when the file is uploaded, but also when I read the model in later. To say nothing of the havoc that could happen if I assumed `#resume=` or `#[:resume]=` was auto updating the extracted data too.

I think in an ideal world, I'd just subclass `Paperclip::Attachment` and make my extracted data peers of `resume_file_name`, `resume_file_size`, `resume_content_type`, `resume_created_at`, extracting that at the same time the mime-type is calculated and the file size is calculated. But looking at the source, those are pretty hard-coded throughout.

Is there another way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured out was to wrap the attachment's setter. That's what'll be called during `initialize` and will give me a chance to detect problems before validation.

The only trick is that since the attachment's setter is created by `has_attached_file` and not inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`, I can't just use `super`, I need to get an explicit reference to the version defined by `has_attached_file` (either by `alias` or, my preference, by `instance_method`):

```
has_attached_file :resume

old_setter = instance_method :resume=
define_method :resume= do |file|
  old_setter.bind(self).call(file)
  begin
    extracted = parse_resume_file(resume.path)
    self.number_of_jobs = extracted.number_of_jobs
    self.highest_level_of_education = extracted.highest_level_of_education
  rescue ResumeParseError => e
    @problem_with_resume = e.message
  end
end
```